# How to get rid of the rows using sequelize

Tags: mariadb, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize.

```
const total = await models.parcel.findAndCountAll({ group: ['status'] });
```

And I got this response.
 But I want to only count not rows on response.
How can I make this? Thank you so much for reading my question.

```
{
    "count": [
        {
            "status": null,
            "count": 8
        },
        {
            "status": "1",
            "count": 5
        },
        {
            "status": "2",
            "count": 3
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "companyName": "hy",
            "invoice": "904103",
            "receiverName": "Rtrt",

        },......
     ]
 }
```

Comment: Just change  findAndCountAll to count and check. 
Ref. Link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just Change `findAndCountAll` to `count`:**

```
await models.parcel.findAndCountAll({ group: ['status'] });
```

To :

```
await models.parcel.count({ group: ['status'] });
```